# get value from object in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

In controller

```
$scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml('This is my html');
$scope.showpopup = function(scopVar,data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

In template:

```
<h2 ng-click ="showpopup('html',html)" ng-bind-html="html" ></h2>
```

I want the value of html scope inside "showpopup" function (i.e:This is my html).When I console it,it print like this

```
 This is my html {$$unwrapTrustedValue=function(), valueOf=function(), toString=function()}
```

So how can I get the actual value( i.e This is my html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log($sce.getTrustedHtml(data));
```

Documentation can be found at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce